# Как можно обойти валидацию, которую прописана для администраторов?

Tags: model, валидация, ruby-on-rails

Добрый день

Вопрос в логике, как лучше реализовать следующее.
Есть таблица пользователей(users) со стандартными полями (nickname, email, password, key), а также поле group.

Группа может принимать значения администратор(admin), либо участник(guest).
Если участник, то пароль и ключ не требуются.

Администраторы создаются через форму, а гостей программно, как можно обойти валидацию, которую прописываю для администраторов? (проверка пароля `has_secure_password` + не пустота и наличие key)

Держать значение group в скрытом inpute мне кажется опасным.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот: http://www.rusrails.ru/active-record-validations#uslovnaya-validatsiya

И тут: http://railstutorial.ru

```
validates :password, presence: true, if: :check_def
validates :key, presence: true, if: :check_def

def check_def
    group == admin
end
```

Или проверка вручную:

```
validates :pass_for_admin

def pass_for_admin
   errors.add(:base, "Set pass, please!") if is_admin? and password.blank? 
end
```

Comment: два момента: 
1. has_secure_password поддерживает if?
2. получается, что нужно group держать как скрытое поле, как это можно обойти? чтобы guest можно было создать только программно?

Comment: 1. has_secure_password это всего-лишь заготовка, которая одной строчкой делает кучу рутины с помощью штатных средств. Соответственно, все методы можно переопределить в модели. 
Читайте доки -- они рулез!

2. Зачем поле? Не надо поле... Если только админы создаются из формы, то в контроллере и ставьте админский статус перед сохранением модели.

Comment: Почитайте тут: http://railstutorial.ru

Comment: спасибо, изучу!